# Triggering a "ViewContent" event with TikTok's Developer Pixel with a custom name

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, tiktok

We are currently trying to convert from a Standard pixel to a Developer Pixel. One of the events we currently have is a "ViewContent" event that has the 'Event Name' of "Product Detail" that triggers on every product page.

With the Developer Pixel I can't find a way to change the 'Event Name'. The only way I can make an event is using:

```js
<script>
  ttq.track('ViewContent', {
    content_id: {{Product Id},
    content_type: 'product',
    content_name: 'Product Detail',
    quantity: 1,
    price: {{Product Price}},
    value: {{Product Price}},
    currency: {{Currency}},
  });
</script>
```

But the 'Content name' is not the same as 'Event Name' and adding for example:

```
event_name: 'Product Detail'
```

only produces an error:
[image: event_name error]

I am pretty much out of ideas and the support is taking its sweet time to respond.

Documention links:
https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1701890973258754

Comment: you can't report custom event names, TikTok only supports 14 events which you can find here: https://ads.tiktok.com/help/article?aid=10028. Event name in your case should be ```ViewContent```

Comment: we have same problem but Tiktok is not much user friendly for that

Comment: @vAhy_The very sad. They seem very reluctant to talk about it when I try.

Comment: @SebastianJohansson one of my colleagues says. Its because the Chinese want to know everything and if you have your custom events they will be lost